# Can`t run compile qt application. Qt Creator is ignoring slashes

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, mingw, qt5

I`ve just installed Windows 7 (64bit) and Qt 5.0.1. And after that I can't run any Qt program. I tried to re-install the library, MinGW and Qt Creator. I also tried to build the library myself, but it didn't help. It's ignoring all slashes. Here are some screens: http://imgur.com/O2UOGNJ and https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdXdb.jpg

Comment: What do your #include statements look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running mingw32-make from the Windows command prompt, cmd.exe

I noticed that your terminal uses forward slashes ("C:/MinGW"), which suggests that you're using MSYS. Your Makefile uses backslashes ("C:\Qt"), which MSYS might not parse properly.

Comment: I solved this problem 2 weeks ago and forgot to wrote the solution.
I installed git with !!!DANGER!!! option and after removing it and installing with standart conf. it works!!